# Google Cloud Endpoints with another oAuth2 provider

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to use another OAuth2 provider with Google Cloud Endpoints? I mean for example, get authentication from Facebook and use it the same way we use Google Account Auth (using gapi js and putting User class on `@ApiMethod`)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716674/facebook-login-in-google-cloud-endpoints/22495862#22495862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  I came across someone else asking this question and the answer from the google folks (if I remember correctly) was that the endpoints user authentication currently only supports Google accounts.

Comment: Is there a way to implement an alternative? Like storing User in the session? (I just discovered that session also does not work in Google Cloud Endpoint)

Comment: Sure, you can implement any alternative you want, and you can pass your systems' tokens via endpoints, but you will have to implement the authentication yourself.

Comment: the problem here is how to control the user session, because Google Endpoint not provide session, right?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.

Comment: You can use endpoints with Sessions enabled. You just need to enable them in your appengine-web.xml using 
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

Comment: @InsaurraldeAP it's not true. You can either implement your own auth schema or implement OAuth with some other provider.

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement your own `Authenticator` and update `@Api` configuration. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365858/google-cloud-endpoints-and-users-authentication) a simple authenticator will look like this:

```
public class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    @Override
    public User authenticate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (token != null) {
            // apply your Facebook/Twitter/OAuth2 authentication
            String user = authenticate(token);
            if (user != null) {
                return new User(user);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And your API definition

```
@Api(name = "example", authenticators = {MyAuthenticator.class})
```

More about custom authenticators you can find in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Authenticator.html).

Comment: Is there a python equivalent?

Comment: @JanuszSkonieczny I've no idea whether or not it's available for python, you should probably ask a new question on SO

Comment: anyone know how to put the data inside the header from android client?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example exchanging a Facebook access token for one generated by my application, and validating it from within an endpoints method:

https://github.com/loudnate/appengine-endpoints-auth-example

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Endpoints allow you to recover User, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletContext into you API methods by injecting it as parameters.

It is not OAuth2 but here is a begining of a solution:
https://www.yanchware.com/custom-authentication-for-google-cloud-endpoints/

The proposed solution is to inject HttpServletRequest in specific api methods to access the session.