# GAE: Authenticating via native iOS Facebook client?

Tags: python, ios, iphone, facebook, google-app-engine

I'm developing an application where the user will be able to log in via his Facebook account to use my GAE backend. I know that I have to first create a Facebook session on my iOS device (via the Facebook SDK or [SimpleAuth](http://simpleauth.io)) and pass it to GAE, but how do I do that? I know there is an option to use [Lean-Engine](http://www.lean-engine.com), however it is Java based and my app is in Python and the iOS classes aren't quite that ready yet.

I'd like to use the Endpoints API to exchange data between the iOS device and GAE, but apparently it requires to use a Google account to use for login, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios#Python_Adding_a_sign-in_dialog_to_your_iOS_client) article. However, this is not as crucial. I want to avoid the user having to fill-in any kind of username/password to log in to the backend application.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook login in Google Cloud Endpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716674/facebook-login-in-google-cloud-endpoints)