# google endpoint custom auth python

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to implement a secure google cloud endpoint in python for multi-clients (js / ios / android)

I want my users to be able to log by three ways loginForm / Google / Facebook.

I read a lot of docummentation about that but I didn't realy understood how I have to handle connection flow and session (or something else) to keep my users logged.

I'm also looking for a way to debug my endpoint by displaying objects like Request for exemple.

If someone know a good tutorial talking about that, it will be verry helpfull.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For request details, add 'HttpServletRequest' (java) to your API function parameter.
For Google authentication, add 'User' (java) to your API function parameter and integrate with Google login on client.
For twitter integration, use Google app-engine OpenID.
For facebook/loginForm, its all on you to develop a custom auth.

Comment: Ok I think for OpenId the Google doc is enough but do you know a good tutorial or exemple to implement facebook ok a loginForm in python?

Comment: *facebook or a loginForm

Comment: some more directions about facebook login at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716674/facebook-login-in-google-cloud-endpoints