# Google Cloud Endpoints User Token authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, jwt

I´m currently designing a REST Api that will run on Google Cloud Endpoints and will be consumed from Web and Android apps. There shouldn't be a need for a google account fot the authentication. I'm wondering how to do the user auth for it.

I´ve read this post:
http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

How to implement it on GAE?

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

> There shouldn't be a need for a google account for the authentication.

Depends what you want to use for authentication. Here's [a vague explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716674/facebook-login-in-google-cloud-endpoints) on how to do it with Facebook.

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872240/google-cloud-endpoints-with-another-oauth2-provider) that says it can't be done without a Google account. [Here are](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js#Java_Adding_authentication_support_with_OAuth_20) [the docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) on how to do it with a Google account.