# Google cloud endpoints and Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, google-identity-toolkit

On the client side I have Android users I wish to authenticate using Google Identity Toolkit. I'll mainly be using email/password authentication but i'm also looking into federated logins. I'm just not sure how to use the Identity Toolkit on Google cloud endpoints. So far the only thing i know for sure is i can't use get_current_user() method to validate a user.

I came across this user authentication API explorer demonstration on [google's website](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/identitytoolkit/v3/)  which uses identity toolkit. This is what I want to do, but i don't know *how* to do it. I couldn't find a proper documentation that shows how to authenticate users on Cloud Endpoints using Google Identity Toolkit API.

A step by step guide would be great!

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872240/google-cloud-endpoints-with-another-oauth2-provider/27457360#27457360

Answer (score 0):

We could do it with this data:

```yaml
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: implicit
    type: oauth2
    x-google-audiences: [PROJECT_ID]
    x-google-issuer: https://identitytoolkit.google.com/
    x-google-jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys
```